# Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on boolean when click on any of top nav categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category

When I click on any of the categories listed in the top nav I go to a blank page with the message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on boolean in magentopath/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php on line 134
```

It's a multistore, until now both stores were running the theme `eTheme - BuyShop ver. 2.1` and were working ok.

But now we had to install the theme `mgstheme claue_v1.5.1` on one of the stores.

So now the configuration of each store is:

[image: configuration of one store]
[image: configuration of the other store]

Now the store with the new theme `mgstheme claue_v1.5.1` installed do not list any category. I followed the files to an empty collection of categories.

in `app/code/design/frontend/mgstheme/claue/template/megamenu/navigation.phtml`
there is `$megaMenu = $this->getMegamenuItems()` and $megaMenu is empty.

in app/code/local/MGS/Megamenu/Block/Megamenu.php is the getMegamenuItems() method.

```
public function getMegamenuItems(){
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $menuCollection = Mage::getModel('megamenu/megamenu')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($store)
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1)
        ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
    ;
    return $menuCollection;
}
```

And it returns nothing. The categories are created and worked fine in the nav menu before changing the theme.

And the store with the previous theme seems to work ok, but when click on a category, then a blank page with the error `Call to a member function setLayer() on boolean` is displayed.

I'm not sure where I should to begin looking for the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should look first where the error message says to look : `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php on line 134`

You will see this line :

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($this->getLayer())
```

The error message means that Magento failed to create the block : the result of `$this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)` should be an object and it is a boolean (`false` I guess).

If I were you, I will do some debug with a `Mage::log($filterBlockName)` before this line (or with x-debug if you know how to do it) to see what type of block failed and why this type does not exist.

Comment: so $filterBlockName is `catalog/layer_filter_attribute`, but `$this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)` is empty (null/false). I look into app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php but I don't see here anything out of place.
It is a great first step to look for, but seems that I'm stuck again...

Comment: Seems that Attribute.php extends from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract` and there is called a template in `app/design/frontend/default/buyshop/template/catalog/layer` called filter.phtml. But there is no filter.phtml, so probably the fallback system of magento is failing for some reason and is not finding the template. I copied the template in it's place but still same error.

Comment: Can you check if the `catalog/layer_filter_attribute` has been rewrite by another extension ?  If you can use n98-magerun, you can see it with `magerun dev:module:rewrite:list` and `magerun dev:module:rewrite:conflicts`.

Comment: There is conflict only with checkout modules and 2 adminhtml modules none of them seems to have relation with filters. `catalog/layer_filter_attribute` is rewritten by `MGS_Mpanel_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute`, though this theme is not active in this store, it is from the other store. I see that `catalog/layer_filter_price` is overwritten by `MGS_Mpanel_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price` and price filter is working. I commented the filters in view.php and view.phtml and now it is working, but without filters, so it is not a good solution. I'm still searching.

Comment: Ok, we are progressing. Note that even if the theme is not active on a store, the rewrite is effective (a rewrite is global). If I were you, I will try to undertsand why the result of `$this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)` is `false` with some `Mage::log()` for debbugging. First, I will look in the `createBlock` method (in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` in there is no rewrite of this class) and put some `if($type=="catalog/layer_filter_attribute"){Mage::log(what-ever-can-help-to-debug)}`. Did you look in the `exception.log` file too ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are right. The templates of the theme are not overrriding the actual templates, but the module is overriding catalog/layer_filter_attribute with MGS_Mpanel_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute. This is the problem.